# createJdbcRowSet source code

Tags: java, jdbc, rowset

I'm studying how to create an implementation of a `JdbcRowSet` with the new API
provided with JDBC 4.1

```
RowSetFactory rf = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
JdbcRowSet jdbcrs = rf.createJdbcRowSet();
```

I want to know if the method `createJdbcRowSet` behind the scene do a call to

```
new JdbcRowSetImpl()
```

that was the old way to use a reference implementation of a `JdbcRowSet`.

If I open src.zip I have only the definition of the interface `RowSetFactory` in which that
method is declared so how can I view the current definition?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all the source code from the OpenJDK project. For example here is the implementation of `RowSetFactory` used in Java 7:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/com/sun/rowset/RowSetFactoryImpl.java#RowSetFactoryImpl